# Kafka dotnet Library Losing/dropping Messages in High Availability Producer

Tags: c#, docker, apache-kafka, confluent-platform

## Description

I have a topic that needs to

- guarantee "at least once" sending, and
- have the highest possible availability.

I have set up an asynchronous producer in a loop that sends 1 million random message at a topic "testtopic". The topic "testtopic" is on 3 partitions in my 3 broker cluster and is set to a replication factor of 3.

This all works perfectly under normal circumstances however, I need to test the contingency that a server may go down during a high load of incoming messages.
To create this scenario I begin the producer which will take a couple minutes to send its 1 million messages and during that time I will stop (`docker stop`) whichever broker the quorum has elected as controller(as seen from the logs).

When I do I would expect Kafka's "at least once" guarantee to deliver all 2 million messages even if the controller goes down. However each time I do this I can see a loss of a hundred to several thousand messages.

I have tried setting the producer to be synchronous like so:

```
producer.ProduceAsync("garytest011", key, msgToSend.Msgs.ToString()).Result;
```

however this totally tanks my throughput just as the documentation says it will.
What is the best way to guarantee "at least once" sending without killing my performance?

## How to reproduce

I'm running a 3 broker cluster of ZooKeeper/Kafka on 3 separate vm's
All settings are set to default
In a C# .NET CORE 2.0 console app I create a basic producer like so:
https://github.com/gazareid/gaza-confluent-kafka-dontnet-producer/blob/master/Program.cs

While the process is running I stop the kafka elected controller to simulate a server down.

Because the loop is done 1 million times there should be 1 million messages in the topic. (or more because of at least once processing duplicates)

I count the messages in the topic with the following command:

`docker run --net=host --rm confluentinc/cp-kafka:3.3.1 kafka-run-class kafka.tools.GetOffsetShell --broker-list localhost:29092 --topic testtopic --time -1 --offsets 1 | awk -F ":" '{sum += $3} END {print sum}'`

And I see anywhere from a hundred to several thousand less than 1 million.

Comment: Perhaps more appropriate to file issue at github. You have not mentioned version for example.